# How to return once from database and store in memory in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

What I want to do:

Return a bunch of rows from database, convert in a array stored in memory and make this array visible from the whole project in such a way that other controllers for example can read it. My function is simple as that:

```
class BoardController extends Controller
{

/*
 * returns something like
 * ['name' => 'description', 
    ...
    ]
 * 
 * */
public static function getAll()
{
    $boards = Board::orderBy('ordem')->get();

    $retorno = array();

    foreach($boards as $b)
    {
        $retorno[$b->sigla] = $b->nome;
    }

    return $retorno;
}
}
```

If I just keep calling `BoardController::getAll()` it will again read from database again. I also tried making this call inside a `config` file into a variable and returning it there but laravel gave me a 500 error. So, what is the best practice/way to do it?

Comment: Try using Laravel Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to call the database everytime then the best approach that can be followed here is to use caching and cache the results.

The Approach is simple, You make a Database call once and cache the reaults and the next time you hit the same function you check the cache first whether its empty or not. If its not empty, then return the cached results.

Remember, the cache has a time limit otherwise if you change/update anything in the database then you'll have to clear the cache that is already stored.

Laravel has some features for caching the results. You can see it [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache).

Also You can also view [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/caching-in-laravel-with-speed-comparisons) link for more effective implementation of cache in Laravel.

Hope this helps.